# How do I round out all the corners on a border

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I've added a border that has the `CornerRadius` set to 10. this makes all the corners more round and that's great. However.. I wanted to add another border in the bottom right corner of the parent one, but that makes the corner go sharp.

How do I properly add a border inside my border and keep the corners round without changing the size of the border that's inside.

```
<Border Width="100" Height="100" 
        ClipToBounds="True"
        CornerRadius="10"
        Background="Orange">
    
    <Border Width="50" 
                Height="50" 
                Background="Green" 
                Canvas.Left="50" 
                Canvas.Top="50" Margin="67,67,-17,-17"/>
    
    
</Border>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `CornerRadius` of inside border.

```xml
<Border Width="100" 
        Height="100" 
        ClipToBounds="True"
        CornerRadius="10"
        Background="Orange">

    <Border Width="50" 
            Height="50" 
            Background="Green" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Margin="70 70 0 0"
            CornerRadius="0 0 10 0"/>
</Border>
```

It will be shown like..
[image]

By adjusting the `Alignment` property and `Margin`,
it can be applied as follows.

```xml
<Border Width="100"
        Height="100" 
        ClipToBounds="True"
        CornerRadius="10"
        Background="Orange">
    <Grid>
        <Border x:Name="border1"
                Width="50" 
                Height="50" 
                Background="Green" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Margin="70 70 0 0"
                CornerRadius="0 0 10 0"/>
        <Border x:Name="border2"
                Width="50" 
                Height="50" 
                Background="Green" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Margin="0 70 70 0"
                CornerRadius="0 0 0 10"/>
        <Border x:Name="border3"
                Width="50" 
                Height="50" 
                Background="Green" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="0 0 70 70"
                CornerRadius="10 0 0 0"/>
        <Border x:Name="border4"
                Width="50" 
                Height="50" 
                Background="Green" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="70 0 0 70"
                CornerRadius="0 10 0 0"/>
    </Grid>
            
</Border>
```

[image]